# Document pdf/binary response in RAML

Tags: raml

I am currently writing a documentation for an api which returns a json or a pdf (binary) based on the Accept-Header sent to the system.

How can I specify that the response is of type binary or similar?

Answer (score 0):

In the RAML Spec I found the `type: file` which seems to be what I was looking for. See https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md#file

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define the possible responses as below.

```
  responses:
    200:
      body:
        application/octet-stream:
        .......
        application/json:
        ........
```

In addition, you can also specify ACCEPT header with the enum of possible content types.

```
      headers:
        Accept:
              type: string
              enum: [application/octet-stream, application/json]
          required: true
```